# Google anaytics event track not working google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics

hi i want to track click on button in website for that i added google analytic code in head.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-1"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1');
    </script>
```

and created a goal with event 
[image: google analytic goal creation details]

now i added script in my footer to track on click button.

```
jQuery('.apple').on('click', function() {

        gtag('event', 'apple', {
          'event_category': 'apple',
          'event_label': 'apple',
          'event_action': 'click',
          'value': '1'
        });

});
```

but its not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that might be to do a `dataLayer` push.

```
dataLayer.push({
    event: 'event_name',
    category: 'event_category',
    action: 'event_action'
})
```

I believe the data sent to the `dataLayer` can be fairly freeform, but sticking to the category, action, label pattern might be a good idea when getting started since it's a common GTM setup.

A nice bonus is that if you declare a `dataLayer` variable in global scope *before* GTM loads, it will persist those variables during the page session

```
<script>
    dataLayer = [{
        pageCategory: 'signup',
        visitorType: 'high-value'
    }];
</script>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

A few important items to keep in mind:

- It's important to use variable conventions consistently across pages, which is especially key to align on if there are multiple people writing event emissions to GTM as you're doing above. If the data is a mess on the other side, it won't provide value
- Strategize on where and how to report broader page or session data (as in the second example above) vs sporadic events (such as the first example).
- Without being aware of your specific use case, your value names seem to be a bit specific. For some use cases, specificity is important, but keep in mind that properties like 'category' are meant to allow correlation with other events, so they need to have a certain degree of abstraction.

For example, consider the below.

```
{
    category: 'Fruit',
    action: 'buy',
    label: 'apple'
},
{
    category: 'Fruit',
    action: 'eat',
    label: 'pear'
}
```

Hope this helps! Added some sources below that cover the above and expand further on the subject.

*Sources:*

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Track by datalayer might be a good idea, but there are easier ways to do this.

First you need to enable gtm.click and gtm.linkclick. Just create these triggers:
[all elements click and links only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neb5S.png)
Then you can see what kind of variable was triggered when you click the button you are trying to trace (using GTM view).
You can also enable the built-in variable ** Click Text ** and ** Click Url ** and configure the trigger using them. [click on text and click on url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI2iH.png)